# What can I use for the value of a pattern-specific macro

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I would like the value of a pattern-specific macro to be based on the stem of the pattern.

```
$(BINDIR)/%.gz: LOGFILE := %.dir/%.log
```

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't: the pattern `%` only works for rule matching. The suggested solution based on `$*` also doesn't work correctly for all cases.

The following doesn't look nice, but achieves what you want:

- use lazy evaluation (`=`) to defer content evaluation until recipe execution
- use `$(notdir $@)` to extract the file name part of the target
- use `$(basename ...)` to strip the file ending

```makefile
BINDIR := bin

.PHONY: all
all: $(BINDIR)/test1.gz $(BINDIR)/test2.gz

$(BINDIR)/%.gz: LOGFILE = $(basename $(notdir $@)).dir/$(basename $(notdir $@)).log

$(BINDIR)/test2.gz:
    @echo "logfile for $@ is $(LOGFILE)"

$(BINDIR)/%.gz:
    @echo "logfile for $@ is $(LOGFILE)"
```

Test run:

```
$ make
logfile for bin/test1.gz is test1.dir/test1.log
logfile for bin/test2.gz is test2.dir/test2.log
```

Comment: On of the interesting things with target/pattern-specific macros is that they are inherited by dependencies. If target A is dependent on target B and target A also defines a target-specific macro C, then the macro C is also available in target B. With lazy evaluation the macro C would be evaluated to different values in A and B. Is there  a way to keep the value from A in B?

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you exactly want to achieve based on the fragmentary information provided by your questions. But my gut feeling tells me that you may be approaching the problem from the wrong direction, i.e. within the makefile. Have you considered the alternative approach of setting `SHELL` to a wrapper that decorates each output line from a job with a unique ID, so that you can extract the information you are looking for in a post-processing step from the log of the whole build?

Comment: Maybe I am too brief with my actual use case. At Code Review I have posted a question with the full use case. Please have a look [link] (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/214363/193952)

Answer (score 0):

Why confuse yourself with pattern specific variables? An ordinary one will do, and make things simpler to boot.

In the *recipe* of a pattern rule, `$*` expands to whatever matched the `%` in the rule. (Here I'll use a static pattern rule, just 'cos they are nicer than ordinary pattern rules IMHO.)

```
${BINDIR}/test1.gz ${BINDIR}/test2.gz: ${BINDIR}/%.gz:
    @echo "logfile for $@ is $*.dir/$*.log"
```

Naturally, a variable or two can tidy this up somewhat:

```
logfile = $*.dir/$*.log
targets := $(patsubst %,${BINDIR}/test%.gz,1 2)

${targets}: ${BINDIR}/%.gz:
    @echo "logfile for $@ is ${logfile}"
```